# How to reset the logon for the sql server services?

Tags: sql-server

I changed the logon from NT service accounts to my local account at some point for testing purposes. Now I want to reset this logon back, however, I do not know the credentials!

Is there a way to reset this back to the default logons? Or do i have to uninstall/reinstall sql server so that it resets back to the NT service account logons?

[image: mylogon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use SQL Server Configuration Manager to set the service account for SQL Server services as this ensures correct permissions and settings are applied, which does not get applied via the Service Control Manager.

Follow the instructions [here](https://jackworthen.com/2018/04/11/changing-the-sql-server-service-account-in-sql-configuration-manager/) and when setting the logon account, enter **NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER** for a default instance or **NT SERVICE\MSSQL$< instance name >** as the username and no password. This will select the virtual account created when SQL Server was installed on the server as the service account.

For SQL Server Agent, the account is with **NT SERVICE\SQLServerAgent** for default or **NT SERVICE\SQLAGENT$< instance name >**.

You should also note, Microsoft recommends using dedicated low-privilege service accounts created specifically for the purpose of running SQL Server rather than shared accounts or built-in accounts. From the [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Always run SQL Server services by using the lowest possible user
> rights. Use a MSA, gMSA or virtual account when possible. When MSA,
> gMSA and virtual accounts aren't possible, use a specific
> low-privilege user account or domain account instead of a shared
> account for SQL Server services. Use separate accounts for different
> SQL Server services. Don't grant additional permissions to the SQL
> Server service account or the service groups. Permissions are granted
> through group membership or granted directly to a service SID, where a
> service SID is supported.

You should consider provisioning managed service accounts for use by SQL instead of reverting to the default account.